# Undefined method File::save() (Laravel model)

Tags: php, database, model, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel to build a new web project. I am using Eloquent (its ORM) to do all the database related stuff. I have a SQLite database with two tables: 'images' and 'files'. Therefore, I have two models: 'Image.php' (class Image extends Eloquent) and 'File.php' (class File extends Eloquent).

According to the documentation I am doing it right. I tried to use the Image model and works perfect. Example of typical use of the model:

```
$image = new Image;
$image->val1 = $val1;
$image->val2 = $val2;
$image->save();
```

However and for some reason I do not know, the File model is not working as expected. I checked everything: table name, class name, file name, tables... and seems okay for me. I tried to do basically the same:

```
$file = new File;
$file->val1 = $val1;
$file->val2 = $val2;
$file->save();
```

When trying to run this, I get:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::save()

If I do a var_dump() just before the save, it seems that the model is being loaded:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\File)#133 (4) {
    ["val1"]=> string(8) "abcdef" 
    ["val2"]=> string(10) "ghijkl" 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure the class File doesn't already exist somewhere else.

Comment: Did you add the extends definition for `File`?

Comment: I've seen this when a migration file class was named the same as a model class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File is a reserved word in that case because it is the alias for the below facade (defined in /app/config/app.php)

```
'File' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
```

change the model name to something else, and all of your code should work fine.

Comment: How could I miss this... thank you very much (will accept this answer).

Comment: The same goes for Event, where I had a problem:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::save()

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if you are using any reserved keywords as Model name.
For eg:

Request

File ..etc

Answer (score -1):

For guys who are searching similar problem, remember named of your model class need be singular.

```
class Client extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'promociones';        

}
```

then, in your controller:

```
client = new Client;
```